# Java SE asynchrous call from client

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, client

I have the following problem:

I have a list of elements on the client side and am supposed to send them to the server one by one, through the same port, but not block the client while waiting for the server to respond.

I have been going through various posts on here as well as JAVA SE documentation, but am not sure I have found the answer. I thought I could start a new Callable for each request, but have been unable to find a non-blocking way to send and receive those messages.

From what I read, using Sockets and Output/Input streams would result in blocking, please correct me if I'm wrong.

I by no means expect a full solution, but any pointers on where to look at would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement these asynchronous calls using the non-blocking APIs NIO AND NIO.2. Theres is a great article about it on javaworld.com:

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2853780/core-java/socket-programming-for-scalable-systems.html

I don't know if you have this option, but you can also implement this on a higher level using HTTP services. Once I answered a question like this for web services. You can take a look here:

[Asynchronous call from java web service to .net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140561/asynchronous-call-from-java-web-service-to-net-application/25316239#25316239)